# Generic method to fill an array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm learning java for school and the subject is generic methods. I need to write an application that has a generic method to "fill" an array of any type with the same element. but its not working... can anyone help me :

```
package pack.switchshift;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Filler {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int[] intArr = new int[10];
        String[] stringArr = new String[10];
        double[] doubleArr = new double[10];

        genFill(intArr, 0);
        genFill(stringArr, "0");
        genFill(doubleArr, 0.0);

        for (int element : intArr){
            System.out.print(element);
        }
    }

    private static <T> void genFill(T[] arr, T element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = element;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple approaches at this and spent some hours researching, but I'm still not getting it.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>   The method `genFill(T[], T)` in the type `Filler` is not applicable for the arguments `(int[], int)`
>   The method `genFill(T[], T)` in the type `Filler` is not applicable for the arguments `(double[], double)` at pack.switchshift.Filler.main(Filler.java:11)

Comment: For primitive types, you have to use their boxed version.

Comment: The `T` is not useful in this case; your method signature should just be `private static void genFill(Object[] arr, Object element)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics doesn't always work for primitive types (I wrote always because you can pass a primitive `int` type to a parameter of type `T`. In which `int` will auto-boxed to `Integer`). You can't create an `ArrayList<int>`, similarly you can't pass an `int[]` or any other primitive type array where a `T[]` array is expected. You have to pass an `Integer[]` instead. Similarly pass `Double[]` instead of `double[]`.

Think of it this way, the generic method is compiled to a type erased method by the compiler. In that process, the type parameter `T` here is erased to it's left-most bound `Object`. So, your method after compilation is equivalent to:

```
private static void genFill(Object[] arr, Object element)
```

Now, you can understand you can't pass an `int[]` where an `Object[]` is needed.

Comment: 'Generics doesn't always work for primitive types' In which primitive type it work ??

Comment: @NiksTyagi Well, you can pass a primitive int, say `0` to type parameter `T`. It will be boxed to `Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) and all of its variants.

Comment: Arrays.fill provides a generic solution for all Objects, plus overloaded versions for all the primitive types. I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use primitives. You can do this because `T` actually means that some Object will be 
put instead of T, so you should use primitive wrappers instead .

```
Integer [] intArr = new Integer [10];
String [] stringArr = new String[10];
Double [] doubleArr = new Double [10];
```

Comment: I edited it like you suggested and it works now... hopefully this is also what is actually requested in the assignment :)